# Colourize a grayscale image using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a grayscale image created using Pillow – it's mode `L` – and I'd like to save it as shades of a single colour, so that instead of shades from black-to-white, it's shades from cyan-to-white.

So, say I was doing this:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

i = Image.open("old_img.jpg")
g = ImageOps.grayscale(i)
g.save("new_img.jpg")
```

What could I do to save it as cyan-to-white, rather than black-to-white?  I'm going to do similar with other grayscale images for magenta-to-white and yellow-to-white too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your image to the "L" mode (luminosity, grayscale), and then use the [`.colorize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.colorize) method instead of the `.grayscale()` one:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

i = Image.open("old_img.jpg").convert("L")
g = ImageOps.colorize(i, black="cyan", white="white")
g.save("new_img.jpg")
```

or just add the command

```
g = ImageOps.colorize(g, black="cyan", white="white")
```

after applying the `.grayscale(i)` method (because it converts the image to the "L" mode, too):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

i = Image.open("old_img.jpg")
g = ImageOps.grayscale(i)
g = ImageOps.colorize(g, black="yellow", white="white")
g.save("new_img.jpg")
```

You may set other desired color in the `black=` parameter of the `.colorize()` method.

Comment: That's great, thanks! I tried so many things and completely missed (or maybe misused) the `colorize()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that with `matplotlib.imshow`:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

i = Image.open("frog.jpg")
g = ImageOps.grayscale(i)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(np.array(g), cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: original image of frog] [image: frog with a blue color]